# How to implement infrastructure Service in Cqrs Architecture?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs, onion-architecture

I intend to implement Infrastructure services in a project that uses the CQRS architecture.
The key point is that we are going to cache the Infrastructure service data in this project.
And finally, use this data in command and also for the query.
And in the end how should I implement this Infrastructure service in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is not simply a question of how to build a class but rather how to build a background service that handles events (via message queues) that loads data to your read database which is consumed by your read API.

You might want to give a read about [Reactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) and [CQRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)

Comment: Thanks for your question , but I want to know how implement a web service on cqrs project
I mean, in the same Solution, or, for example, take a different solution in general and how to use these services in the Command and Query layer....

Comment: @John, the answer to your question could be very subjective and can easily variate depending on all the requirements of a system. You might want to give the e-shops microservice github project of microsoft: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

Comment: In general, I agree with you because it's actually an Infrastructure service that can be implemented in any way.
Because business has implemented somewhere else, we just use it
I gave you the answer as the correct answer

Comment: @John, I hope you find a good way man, generally, an infrastructure service is just an abstract concept that maybe implementing an underlying, API, DB, queue, Redis, NoSQL accessing layers. It really depends on your requirements and use-cases man.

Comment: Well, right after completing the question in StackOverflow, I went looking for this.
And I arrived at the same conclusion as your conclusion
And this article helped me a lot:
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2385-application-services-vs-infrastructure-services-vs-domain-services.htm?site-photo=732